# sql oracle - distinct all columns

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the 2 below tables. I want to get all modules where the first char of fk_class includes in array of number.

**ESP_MODULE**

```
moduleId  label
AJ-03     xxxx
PTM-01    yyyy
AN-10     wwww
```

**ESP_MODULE_CLASS**

```
assignId  fk_class fk_module
1           1EM1     AJ-03
2           1EM2     AJ-03
3           2A1      AN-10
4           2A2      AN-10
5           5GC1     AN-10
6           5GC1     PTM-01
7           5GC3     PTM-01
```

I tried with the below query but i get a duplicated value.

**Query**

```
select * from ESP_MODULE m inner join ESP_MODULE_CLASS mc ON mc.fk_module = m.moduleId WHERE SUBSTR(mc.fk_class,1,1) IN (1,2);
```

Comment: Oracle `SELECT` queries don't support arrays, so your question doesn't make sense.  Please also show the result set you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want `exists`?

```
select m.*
from ESP_MODULE m 
where exists (select 1
              from ESP_MODULE_CLASS mc 
              where mc.fk_module = m.moduleId and
                    SUBSTR(mc.fk_class, 1, 1) IN ('1', '2')
             );
```

Note that `substr()` returns a string, so the proper comparison is to a string.  You might find that condition easier to write as a regular expression:

```
where regexp_like(mc.fk_class, '^[12]')
```